# how to change height between UITableView and Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationbar, ios7

got a `UITableViewStyleGrouped`and `UITableViewStylePlain` by changes in storyboard, found that, top edge of plain table view sticks to navigation bar, while top gap in grouped style somehow because of header view.

[image]

But, as picture show, gap "a" is bigger than  "b", why? Are there any hidden elements around "a"? How to manage this gap so that it could be also stuck with bar?

What's the default size of gap "a" and "b"? How to make "a" equal to "b", like "setting"

[image]

#### below are my try-out

---

#### tried set `heightForHeaderInSection:` and `viewForHeaderInSection:` like below

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return 0.0f;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
UIView * header = [[UIView alloc] init];
header.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:header];

return header;
}
```

[image]

---

#### tried `heightForFooterInSection:` and `viewForFooterInSection:`, like below

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return 0.0f;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
UIView * footer = [[UIView alloc] init];
footer.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
[self.view addSubview:footer];
return footer;
}
```

[image]

---

It looks neither of them work as expected, gap "a" is always there and not changed.

The weird is, height of header and footer is still there, looks a minium height,

#### even if setting their height zero.

Comment: I've run into the same problem. My conclusion is that if you return 0, then it defaults to display a standard empty section header with a default height. It won't even call the methods for the header view and the header text. If you return a different value, e.g. 0.5, then it calls the header view and text methods and displays the correct section header with the specified height.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly **why** your issue is occurring, but a workaround to get the grouped tableview "stuck" to the bottom of the navigation bar:

```
CGFloat myInset = *HEIGHT OF GAP A*
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-myInset, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: trie your code, it looks work! Thanks! But why is there gap "a"? what's the correct look by default grouped table view? Do you know what's the default heights of footer/header

Comment: ah... I found them in storyboard, header/footer are 10. BUT, still can't don't know what the meaning of gap "a". Could you give me any more information? Thanks!

Comment: for default value of header/footer, I found them in storyboard, but still can't find what's the meaning of gap "a". Anyway, is workaround is a trade-off alternative. Thank you, @AndrewRobinson !

Answer (score 1):

Just add this code in `ViewDidLoad` method:

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it's can help you . I am thinking you need to change footer height .

implement those UITableView-delegate methods:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return 50.0f;
}
```

or this delegate methods

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
 - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section

 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug I have opened from the first beta. It's working with this option meanwhile:

```
if([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
        if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568.0) {
            //iphone5
            sectionsTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568);
        }
        else {
            //iphone4s
            sectionsTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
        }
    }
```

Bugreport issue #14310190

Comment: @iOS.dev resize your tableview full screen in storyboard.

Comment: yes. tableview is full screen. Actually, I didn't find place to change tableview's size except cell row height, header/footer

Comment: @iOS.dev in the Interface builder. as usual. Your issue is your tableview seems not in a full screen. It will work with my code. I had the same issue from the first beta Xcode 5 and opened a ticket. It's still open for Apple Support.

Comment: so you mean, this issue is still there even in official Xcode 5?

Comment: @iOS.dev Yes.My ticket is still open

Answer (score 0):

Before each section, you have a header. After each section, you have a footer. What you have marked as "a" is the header of section 0. What you have marked as "b" is the combination of the footer of section 0 and the header of section 1.

So to have the same appearance as the Settings app, you want code like this:

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0)
        return 20.0f;
    return 10.0f;
}

- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 10.0f;
}
```

Note that returning 0 will not work. It seems to have the effect that the table view reverts to some default empty header or section.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you still interested, the reason why there's the space at the top of the table view, is because that's the default header of the TableView. To get ride of it, just add this to your tableViewController

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.tableView.bounds.size.width, 0.0f)];
```

That will draw it right under the top of the view controller. You can change the value of 0.0 to whatever you so desire.

Answer (score 0):

Return the minimum value (not 0) in the table view's heightForFooterInSection API (say 0.1). This will remove the default space (which is around 10 px) from the bottom of the section as you shown in yellow and red color.